# PHP / simpleXML - Preventing duplicate XML values from being inserted into an array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

The code below successfully retrieves and displays the name and price elements in the XML file.

I want to also display the text of the XML "store" values, but do not want any duplicate store names displayed.

So I created the storeArray to hold the name of the stores, but do not know how to prevent duplicate store names from being inserted into the array.

In the code below, "Best Buy" is displayed twice (when using the second foreach loop), but I only want it to display once.

Is there a way to insert the names of the stores in the storeArray and also prevent duplicate store names from being inserted?

Or is there a better method to do this than the code below?

```
 $xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
 $storeArray = array();
 foreach($xmlDoc->product as $Product) {
   echo "Name: " . $Product->name . ", ";
   echo "Price: " . $Product->price . ", ";

   $storeArray[] =  $Product->store;
   echo "<br>";
 }

 foreach ($storeArray as $store) {
   echo $store . "<br>";
 }
```

XML file:

```
<products>

  <product type="Electronics">
    <name> Desktop</name>
    <price>499.99</price>
    <store>Best Buy</store>
  </product>

  <product type="Electronics">
    <name>Lap top</name>
    <price>599.99</price>
    <store>Best Buy</store>
  </product>

  <product type="Hardware">
    <name>Hand Saw</name>
    <price>99.99</price>
    <store>Lowes</store>
  </product>

</products>
```

Comment: erm just check to see if the array already contains it before you add    ??

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to take advantage of the fact that associative array keys are always unique. You can use the element or attribute name as the key, and the isset() array function to see if that key exists or not. For example:

```
 $xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
 $storeArray = array();
 foreach($xmlDoc->product as $Product) {
     echo "Name: " . $Product->name . ", ";
     echo "Price: " . $Product->price . ", ";

     if(!isset($storeArray[$Product->store])
     $storeArray[$Product->store] =  $Product->store;

     echo "<br>";
 }

 foreach ($storeArray as $store) {
     echo $store . "<br>";
 }
```

Arrays in PHP can be both numerically indexed and associative at the same time.

I'm also trying to think of a more elegant way to accomplish this, this is just the top of my head answer. Will edit as necessary.

Comment: This works, though the advantage of this over the other (in_array) technique would be that you shouldn't need to check before adding it.  I.E. the `if(!isset...` is not needed.

Comment: Also worth noting that this technique would work if you wanted to store more than just the name in the array.

Comment: @RobBaillie, my issue with in_array() is efficiency. It's cheaper to check for a key O(n) I believe, than checking the entire array for a value.

Comment: I presume that statement is based on an in-depth understanding of how PHP implements in_array ;-)  It seems fair enough - and you should note that I didn't state I had anything against your method, it's perfectly reasonable.  However, the check isn't needed.  You can just overwrite the value each time.  Might be slower, might be quicker - should probably benchmark if you cared about that level of performance.  In those cases you may also want to consider memory usage and the duplication of data with key->value being the same.

Comment: @RobBaillie nah bro, it's all good. When I was in college for CS, performance was kin to God, so it's kept with me at all times.

Answer (score 0):

You can reorganise how the `$storeArray` is defined, as stated in the other answer, but it is also worth considering "`in_array`".  This checks is the value is already in the array:

```
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
$storeArray = array();
foreach($xmlDoc->product as $Product) {
   echo "Name: " . $Product->name . ", ";
   echo "Price: " . $Product->price . ", ";

   if( !in_array( $Product->store, $storeArray ) {
      $storeArray[] =  $Product->store;
   }
   echo "<br>";
 }

 foreach ($storeArray as $store) {
   echo $store . "<br>";
 }
```

Doing it this way means that the array remains numerically indexed (this may or may not be important).

Comment: Regarding the result being numerically indexed, you can discard the keys once it's fully populated with a call to `array_values`. `in_array` has to iterate over all values, so scales very poorly.

Comment: Thanks! The in_array code you suggested should work, however it is not preventing duplicate values from being put in the array. However, this code works: $practiceArray = array('Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3');
echo "In Array tester -- <br>";
if (in_array("Product1", $practiceArray)) {
echo "Is in array";
}
else {
echo "NOT in array";
}